# Am not able to see foreign keys for any table in my mysql database

Tags: mysql, key, cascade

New to mysql and have been told by many, that creating foreign keys in mysql is not necessary? how will table relationships be consistent and cascading would be done then? Where can i find info about what foreign key has been created on my mysql tables? desc table_name or show create table_name is not giving any info....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys in MySQL work only with InnoDB tables. They *do* appear in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. You might not actually have foreign keys defined, because MySQL *silently ignores* the `column type REFERENCES othertable(column)` syntax; only separate `FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES othertable(column)` foreign key definitions have effect in `CREATE TABLE`.

Related reading: [CREATE TABLE in MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) (search for "inline references specifications")

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not understand " MySQL silently ignores the column type REFERENCES othertable(column) syntax; only separate FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES othertable(column) foreign key definitions have effect in CREATE TABLE " ...if there is no effect of creating a foreign key in mysql, how cascading will be maintained across tables eg if a record is deleted or new record inserted how there will be a check that an invalid value is not entered....

Comment: There are two ways to define foreign keys in a `CREATE TABLE` statement: in the column specification itself (_inline_), and as a separate `FOREIGN KEY` definition. Both are accepted (do not cause any error), but the inline definitions are ignored, so you must use separate `FOREIGN KEY` definitions, or you must add your foreign keys _after_ you've created the table.

Comment: thanks, i know how to create foreign keys...so are you saying if a foreign key is created on a table using inline specification , we wont be able to see that a foreign key has been created on this table later on? Also, please tell me why foreign keys are not important in mysql....thanks again!

Comment: If you define your foreign keys using the inline specification, _they will not be created at all_. Foreign keys are important to people who use MySQL, just like they are important to people who use other database engines. They have just been not important to MySQL _developers_, because they have wrongly assumed for a long time that application logic can provide the same benefits.

Comment: Oh okay..thanks..actually in database which I am using i see lot of discrepencies in table relationships, i think if foreign keys had been maintained this should have had resolved the problem to much extent?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! you resolved lot of my confusion...thanks for replying